# Integrate Authorize.net ARB payment gateway in php using SDK

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am trying to integrate authourize.net payment gateway in php using sdk on github from https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php link. i have downloaded the sdk in my root folder and updated composer as well
but still am getting following error

**D:\xammp\htdocs\JustFaster>php D:\xammp\htdocs\Faster\charge-credit-card.php**

> Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xammp\htdocs\Faster\charge-credit-card.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;D:\xammp\php\PEAR') in D:\xammp\htdocs\Faster\charge-credit-card.php on line 3

I have tried to change the required files path starting from my root folder but still the problem is not resolved.

***require 'vendor/autoload.php';  --- in sdk
i have changed it to  --- require 'sdk-php-1.8.8/autoload.php';
sdk-php-1.8.8 is the sdk downloaded from github.***

Please somebody help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

At the same time please can i get the sample code to create ARB subscription and get the status of that subscription with getSubscriptionStatus($subscriptionId) method.

Awaiting for a response..

Comment: you'll probably get answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory